# How do I print out 'NULL' or '0' values for column values when an element isn't found?

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I need to loop through a set of values (less than 10) and see if they are in a table. If so, I need to print out all of the record values, but if the item doesn't exist, I still want it to be included in the printed result, although with NULL or 0 values. So, for example, the following query returns:

```
select * 
  from ACTOR 
 where ID in (4, 5, 15);
```

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
| ID | NAME                        | DESCRIPTION | ORDER_ID | TYPE |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
|  4 | [TEST-1]                    |             |        3 | NULL |
|  5 | [TEST-2]                    |             |        4 | NULL |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
```

But I want it to return

```
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
| ID | NAME                        | DESCRIPTION | ORDER_ID | TYPE |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
|  4 | [TEST-1]                    |             |        3 | NULL |
|  5 | [TEST-2]                    |             |        4 | NULL |
|  15| NULL                        |             |        0 | NULL |
+----+-----------------------------+-------------+----------+------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you need to do it at all? I think it will be much more effective to check returned ids at server side (i.e. with php or whatever you use) rather than running all these crazy queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the output you want, you first have to construct a derived table containing the `ACTOR.id` values you desire.  UNION ALL works for small data sets:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 4 AS actor_id
          FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5
          FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 15
          FROM DUAL) x
```

With that, you can OUTER JOIN to the actual table to get the results you want:

```
   SELECT x.actor_id,
          a.name,
          a.description,
          a.orderid,
          a.type
     FROM (SELECT 4 AS actor_id
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 5
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 15
             FROM DUAL) x
LEFT JOIN ACTOR a ON a.id = x.actor_id
```

If there's no match between `x` and `a`, the `a` columns will be null.  So if you want orderid to be zero when there's no match for id 15:

```
   SELECT x.actor_id,
          a.name,
          a.description,
          COALESCE(a.orderid, 0) AS orderid,
          a.type
     FROM (SELECT 4 AS actor_id
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 5
             FROM DUAL
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 15
             FROM DUAL) x
LEFT JOIN ACTOR a ON a.id = x.actor_id
```

Comment: +1 This is similar to my answer, but more clearly explained, I think :) @Vladimir, One point to note here is the difference between my UNION and @OMG's UNION ALL. If your values are 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, UNION ALL will give you 6 rows in your result set, whereas UNION will coalesce the duplicates down, giving 4 rows. Just pick which result you'd prefer... Note also that @OMG's given you the Oracle answer (with DUAL) where I've given you the MySQL answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for that few values, you could do something ugly like this, I suppose:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   (
      SELECT 4 AS id UNION 
      SELECT 5 UNION 
      SELECT 15
    ) ids 
      LEFT JOIN ACTOR ON ids.id = ACTOR.ID
```

(That should work in MySQL, I think; for Oracle you'd need to use DUAL, e.g. `SELECT 4 as id FROM DUAL...`)

Answer (score 0):

That is only possible using a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Comment: Assuming that a temporary table is created and the values are inserted, what would the sql statement look like?

Comment: Am I missing something, or couldn't it be done with [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)?

Comment: @Brad I think you may be missing something. How would you do it with IFNULL?

Comment: @Brad that was my first thought as well, but how can you do IFNULL on a row that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Matt[Gibson]: I suppose you're right. If you want to hard-select rows, even those that don't exist, you're apt to create a cache of the values you want (regardless of existence) and proceed with bringing the matching information in. Good call, and probably best I didn't make an attempt. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE actor_temp (id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO actor_temp VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO actor_temp VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO actor_temp VALUES(15);
select actor_temp.id, ACTOR.* from ACTOR RIGHT JOIN actor_temp on ACTOR.id = actor_temp.id;
DROP TABLE actor_temp;
```

Comment: In theory, you could create the temporary table and populate it separately, therefore creating a faster query if you were to run it multiple times as you wouldn't need to create the temporary table every time you ran the query.

Comment: The problem is that I can't create tables in this database -- not enough privileges.

Comment: @Vladimir Sad! Hopefully you can use Matt Gibson's answer above - that also works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the upper and lower limits on the ID, it's not too bad. Set up a view with all possible ids - the connect by trick is the simplest way - and do an outer join with your real table. Here, I've limited it to values from 1-1000.

```
select * from (
   select ids.id, a.name, a.description, nvl(a.order_id,0), a.type
   from Actor a,
        (SELECT level as id from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000) ids
   where ids.id = a.id (+)
)
where id in (4,5,15);
```

Comment: Yup, that's another way I considered going, but I wasn't sure if there was an easy and similarish way of generating all those rows in MySQL as well as Oracle. But if you can do it, and you know the ID maximum, and your generator query isn't too slow, it's probably a bit cleaner than some other approaches...

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a table that contains expected actor ids?

If so you can left join from it.

```
SELECT * FROM expected_actors LEFT JOIN actors USING (ID)
```